# nginx proxy_pass one file

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have a single file that I want to appear to host but that I don't.  So I write this in my nginx server block:

```
location /d-p27.js {
  proxy_pass https://data.example.com/p/piwik.js;
}
```

After reloading nginx's config, when I test this with `curl -I https://another.example.com/d-p27.js`, I get a 404.  The nginx logs don't say any more than that.

So I try this:

```
location /d-p27.js {
  rewrite ^/d-p27.js$ /p/piwik.js break;
  proxy_pass https://data.example.com/;
}
```

This also 404's.  Any suggestions?

### The solution

Thanks to @RichardSmith, the solution is simply to use an exact match to avoid confusion with other regex's:

```
location = /d-p27.js {
  proxy_pass https://data.example.com/p/piwik.js;
}
```

Comment: 404 returned by your backend or by frontend?

Comment: nginx is returning a 404

Comment: Do you have any other `location` definitions in your configuration - maybe regular expressions to handle URIs that end with `.js`?

Comment: @RichardSmith Aha, yes!  This, plus simply guaranteeing first match by using = rather than regex match, since I want to match only this one file anyway.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If so, please post an answer below. Answers should not be part of the question text as people do not expect to find them there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, but I shouldn't, richardsmith should so I can accept his answer.